# Combine 2 rows into one result MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have checked out some other questions, and I cant seem to find any that answer my specific question.

The following table is the result of this query:

```
SELECT teacher.teacherID, unitName FROM teacher INNER JOIN unit ON teacher.teacherID=unit.teacherID ORDER BY teacherID ASC
```

[image: Table]

What I actually need the result to display is this:

[image: Table 2]

Is there a way to modify my current query so that this can be achieved? I wasn't sure if this was possible in MySQL at all, but as I have learned in the past, you should never underestimate the power of a query! (this was discovered after spending time using messy nested loops trying to manipulate an array, instead i managed to do it all in a query)

EDIT: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3af9/1)

Thanks, and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Awesome site, I have updated question with the SQL Fiddle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT teacher.teacherID, GROUP_CONCAT(unitName)
FROM teacher
INNER JOIN unit ON teacher.teacherID=unit.teacherID
GROUP BY teacher.teacherID
ORDER BY teacherID ASC
```

This query works directly in your SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou this answer worked perfectly! I will accept this as soon as stackoverflow lets me!

Answer (score 2):

A slight tweak to alexn's answer to match your formatting with spaces after the comma:

```
SELECT teacher.teacherID, GROUP_CONCAT(unitName SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM teacher
INNER JOIN unit ON teacher.teacherID=unit.teacherID
GROUP BY teacher.teacherID
ORDER BY teacherID ASC
```

Comment: how would you do this but getting rid of duplicate unitNames ?